# how to add custom ttl for caching on any route in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

Hello I am using Caching module for caching in nest js, as i read in docs you can set ttl time in register function

```
 CacheModule.register({
      ttl: 200000,
      max: 1000
    })
```

and I am quite confused, how can I set custom ttl to any route so if I have, route like this

```
@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
export class TestController {

  @Get('testData')
  getRequest(@Request() req: Request, @Query() query) {
      return "I AM CACHED";
     }

 }
```

so getRequest handler only caches 20 secs for example not 200000

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look on the

- useGlobalIntercptor
- ‘APP_INTERCEPTOR’ if you want to use injection

To apply the caching interceptor on every handler

Here the link https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors